# How to use repository, usecase and repository_impl when working with streambuilder in firebase

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, stream

I was implementing clean architecture while learning it and for future I was able to get the documents when working with usecase, repository and repositoryimpl but when I tried using same way with firebase docs and streambuilder I was not able to do it. I even edited the code and tried to send the stream directly from bloc instead of thos folder but was not able to get this. This is what my event code looklike :-

```
AnimalDataBloc({required this.fetchPetListUseCase}) : super(Stream.empty()) {
  on<FetchDataByFilters>((event, emit) async* {
    yield* _firestore
        .collection('pet_data')
        .limit(event.limit)
        .where(event.leftComparator, isEqualTo: event.rightComparator)
        .snapshots()
        .transform(
      StreamTransformer.fromHandlers(
        handleData: (snapshot, sink) {
          print("result is $snapshot");

          final animalList = transformSnapshot(snapshot);
          sink.add(animalList);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

and this is what my bloc builder looked like :-

```
BlocBuilder<AnimalDataBloc, Stream<AnimalEntityList>>(
  bloc: _animalBloc,
  builder: (context, data) {
    return StreamBuilder<AnimalEntityList>(
        stream: data,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          return BuildAsperSnapShot(
              snapshot: snapshot, themeNotifier: themeNotifier);
        });
  },
),
```

The data in firebase is id, animal name, imageurl and category. How can I achieve it with using the same clean architecture approach